# python ANOVA for variable number of input arrays

Tags: python

I'm implementing the Kruskall-Wallis test in `scipy.stats.kruskal`. Is there some way to enter input arguments for an unknown number of inputs?

For instance, reproducing examples from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kruskal.html)

```
from scipy.stats import kruskal

# 2 input arrays
x1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
x2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
kruskal(x1, x2)
# KruskalResult(statistic=0.2727272727272734, pvalue=0.6015081344405895)

# 3 input arrays
x1 = [1, 1, 1]
x2 = [2, 2, 2]
x3 = [2, 2]
kruskal(x1, x2, x3)
# KruskalResult(statistic=7.0, pvalue=0.0301973834223185)
```

But what if I don't know the number of groups (input arrays) in the first place? I could do something like the following, but it seems inelegant:

```
input_list = [[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]]
if len(input_list) == 2:
    kresult = kruskal(input_list[0], input_list[1])
elif len(input_list) == 3:
    kresult = kruskal(input_list[0], input_list[1], input_list[2])
elif len(input_list) == 4:
    kresult = kruskal(input_list[0], input_list[1], input_list[2], input_list[3])
# and so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [spread operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```py
kresult = kruskal(*input_list)
```